# How to reference a table called `\` (simply just backslash character) in MySQL in a query?

Tags: mysql, naming-convention

Through some unknown circumstances I have a table called "\" in a database.

```
mysql> show tables like '\\';
+-----------------------------+
| Tables_in_in_realestate (\) |
+-----------------------------+
| \                           |
+-----------------------------+
```

On the disk the files are called @005c.

```
user@host:mysql/database/$ ls @005c.*
@005c.frm  @005c.ibd
```

I want to rename it to something more manageable, but I can't reference it in a `RENAME TABLE` query.

```
mysql> RENAME TABLE `\` TO `backslash`
    `> `          <-- it thinks there is an open quote
    -> \c         <-- so I just cancel the query
```

I thought I could escape the "\" with another "\" but that doesn't seem to work either:

```
mysql> RENAME TABLE `\\` TO `backslash`;
ERROR 1017 (HY000): Can't find file: './in_realestate/@005c@005c.frm' (errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
```

How can I reference the table in my `RENAME TABLE` query?

Comment: What was the error when you run `RENAME TABLE \`\\` TO \`backslash\`;`?

Comment: @ypercube there is no error on that one, but it doesn't execute because it believes the backticks quoting isn't finished - there is an open quote because the "closing" backtick was escaped.

Comment: Well, first, you need to punch the person who thought naming a table \ was a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow this query actually works...

```
RENAME TABLE `\` TO backslash; `;
```

Two statements, three backticks in total - neither statement would work by itself but somehow together they do the job. Despite giving an error.

To test this in a vacuum you can do:

```
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `\` ( `foo` int(10) ) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=utf8; `;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`' at line 1
mysql> show tables;
+---------------+
| Tables_in_foo |
+---------------+
| \             |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE `\`; `;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`' at line 1
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Please note that the syntax for this command is quite peculiar: it is the word "DROP" followed by "TABLE" followed by the string "`\`; `;" - that is backtick, then backslash, backtick again and then semi-colon. This is further followed by space, then (**another**) backtick and finally semi-colon.

Comment: I second @AaronBertand's suggestion that the person who named a table `backslash` (have to write it out in full - doesn't appear in comment otherwise) should be beaten soundly round the head :-) (although it was probably some sort of typo error). You should mark your own answer as correct so that anyone with this (unusual) problem can readily find a solution. It may take some time for the system to allow you to do this.

Comment: You could also explicitly point out that the extra backtick appears to be necessary for your query to work. How did you discover this? It seems to be a very weird construct - a single isolated backtick.

Comment: @Vérace I've tried to make it more explicit. Do you think it's clear enough now? I'm open to any and all suggestions about how to explain this weirdness.
To be honest one of my developers discovered the fix and he can't explain how he came up with it, he just lucked out and found something that worked! I'll see if I can figure out how to report this to MySQL themselves.

Comment: I've added an edit explaining the syntax. It may be overkill, but at the same time, the syntax is so strange and convoluted that I think it's worth explicitly writing it out in words - if you feel different, please feel free to remove my edit. As an aside, an accepted bug report on MySQL would be a feather in anyone's cap! :-)

Comment: Reported on bugs.mysql.com - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68676&thanks=3&notify=195

Comment: +1 for that. I always appreciate it when people take the time and effort to make an effort of any sort for F/LOSS projects. In fact, it's a bug to be even able to create a table called backslash in the first place - this fails "mysql> create table 2(billy int);"